How to show that $\sum_{j = 1}^{A \left({n}\right)} \left\{{\frac{n - {j}^{2}}{2\, j}}\right\}$ satisfies Weyl's criterion.
We can write this sum in terms of even ($j = 2k$) and odd ($j = 2k-1$) summation index as
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{A \left({n}\right)} \left\{{\frac{n - {j}^{2}}{2\, j}}\right\} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\lfloor{A \left({n}\right)/2}\rfloor} \left\{{\frac{n}{4\, k}}\right\} + \sum_{k = 1}^{\lceil{A \left({n}\right)/2}\rceil} \left\{{\frac{n}{2 \left({2\, k - 1}\right)} + \frac{1}{2}}\right\}$$
where $A \left({n}\right) = \lfloor{\sqrt{n + 1}}\rfloor - 1$ and {...} is the fractional part.  If both fractional parts sums satisfy Weyl's criterion for equidistribution modulo 1, then I can write
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j = 1}^{A \left({n}\right)} \left\{{\frac{n - {j}^{2}}{2\, j}}\right\} {}\sim{} &
\sum_{j = 1}^{A \left({n}\right)} \frac{1}{2} = 
\frac{1}{2}\, A \left({n}\right) \sim
\frac{1}{2} \left({\sqrt{n + 1} - 1 + O \left({1}\right)}\right) \sim
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n}
- \frac{1}{2}
+ O \left({1}\right)
+ O \left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right) \\ {}\sim{} &
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n}
+ O \left({1}\right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The following table shows that Weyl's criterion is being met or nearly met.  I think that the two even and odd sums may be easier to prove.  A correction, the third column in the table should read as $\lfloor{A[n]/2}\rfloor$.

This is part of a bigger problem, so if an exact solution can be found for
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{A \left({n}\right)} \lfloor{\frac{n - {j}^{2}}{2\, j}}\rfloor$$ would be a super bonus!
This is an extension of problem Summation of square root fractional part which is becoming part of my research.  So please use this a reference for additional details.
